Size of maximum matching in bipartite graph with degree restrictions
I am having trouble with the following problem:

Let $G = (A, B, E)$ be a bipartite graph on $22$ vertices, of which $20$ vertices have degree five and $2$ vertices have degree three. Find $\nu(G)$, where $\nu(G)$ denotes the size of a maximum matching of $G$.

By Kőnig's Theorem we have that $\nu(G)$ equals the size of a minimum vertex cover of $G$, denoted by $\tau(G)$. I resorted to finding $\tau(G)$. By the Handshaking Lemma we know that $G$ has $53$ edges, and by the inequality $\tau(G) \geq \frac{|E|}{\Delta(G)}$ (where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of $G$) we have that $\tau(G) \geq 11$. I've tried to infer more about $\tau(G)$, such as something involving this identity due to Gallai: $\tau(G) + \alpha(G) = |V|$ (where $\alpha(G)$ is the size of a maximum independent set).
But I'm not sure whether this is the right approach, perhaps I'm overlooking something. Any help is appreciated.

Aren't you done already? If $\tau(G) \geq 11$, you have already covered all vertices of $G$ in your matching. So $\tau(G)$ is exactly $11$.

This is true only if $|A| = |B| = 11$ right? If so, I think I could infer that $\alpha(G) \leq 11$ from the identity in my post. But since $G$ is bipartite $\alpha(G) = 11$ and the rest follows.

@JLGL For this setup, we can indeed show that $|A| = |B| = 11$, and further more than $A, B$ each have exactly 1 vertex with degree 3.  Hint: $ 5 \times 10 < 5 \times 10 + 3 \times 2$.
